# Android, How to use a LoaderManager & Loader in conjunction with sqldatabase

Tags: java, android, sql

I have a database with _id etc.

I want to load this data via a LoaderManager & Loader to an adapter but I'm not sure how.

Can anyone explain an easy yet efficient way to use a LoaderManager & loader with an sqldatabase ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nicest way I've found to use the `AsyncTaskLoader` has been detailed in [this tutorial](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html) on the Android Design Patterns blog. This example is returning a `SampleItem` object but it wouldn't be much to port the code to return a `Cursor` and then perform the database query in the `loadInBackground` method.

I thoroughly recommend you have a read through all the parts of the series, it's a good read :)

Comment: So following this with a Cursor, where would I access the cursor object to get the data to map to my adapter?

Comment: I would load the cursor in the `loadInBackground` method and return it. At which point you would be able to access the cursor in your activity/fragment implementation of the `onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)` method as defined in the [LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html) interface.

Comment: Thank you, I shall work on this and reply my progress/thoughts

Comment: The only problem is that that tutorial uses a Content provider. I dont want to share my database details with any other application so how can go around this?

Comment: You just need to use your own database code as appropriate in the `loadInBackground` method. There is no need to use a Content provider or resolver. Just get hold of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` and make your database query.

Comment: I understand that but im having problems here, in the public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {} method as this is where he passes a CONTENT_URI to return, but i dont want to do that so i just null that and instead i receive a null pointer exception..., So how do i get around this?

Comment: In that method i currently have, 
CursorLoader x = new CursorLoader(Myactivity.this);

Comment: Ah I think I see the confusion now, rather than using CursorLoader you need to write your own implementation of AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor> for the sake of this example call it `MyLoader`. Then rather than creating a new CursorLoader you want to make a `new MyLoader(Myactivity.this)`. There shouldn't be any need for a content uri at all.

Comment: okay i think i'm almost there, i wrote a loader class: public class MyLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Cursor>>{}, Just like the tutorial,
But in the activity the problem still exists in the onCreateLoader. I get the message: Cannot convert from MyLoader to Loader.MyLoader

Comment: The onCreate Loader contains:
public Loader<MyLoader> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
  
  return new MyLoader(MyActivity.this);
 }

Comment: Looks like the LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks you have defined is wrong. It should be set as LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Cursor>>, the onCreateLoader method should then be marked as returning a Loader<List<Cursor>>.